# How to get all CAPS chapter titles

Tags: memoir, chapters, capitalization

Trying to get all CAPS chapter titles. Using the following, only the ToC chapter title is all CAPS:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\renewcommand{\chaptitlefont}{\MakeUppercase}
\begin{document}

\tableofcontents*

\chapter*{Preface}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Preface}  

\chapter{Sample Title}

\end{document}
```

What does one do to get Preface, and Sample Title to be in all CAPS as well?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

According to the [`memoir`](http://ctan.org/pkg/memoir) [user manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/memoir/memman.pdf), a chapter title is set via `\printchaptertitle`. An example of its usage and redefinition for the `bringhurst` chapter style (section *20.4.1 The chapter style*, p 354) is:

```
%% Bringhurst chapter style
\makechapterstyle{bringhurst}{%
  \renewcommand{\chapterheadstart}{}
  \renewcommand{\printchaptername}{}
  \renewcommand{\chapternamenum}{}
  \renewcommand{\printchapternum}{}
  \renewcommand{\afterchapternum}{}
  \renewcommand{\printchaptertitle}[1]{%
    \raggedright\Large\scshape\MakeLowercase{##1}}
  \renewcommand{\afterchaptertitle}{%
    \vskip\onelineskip \hrule\vskip\onelineskip}
}
```

It's obvious how `\printchapterstyle` has been redefined to set the contents in lowercase. In a similar vein, you're most like after

```
\renewcommand{\printchaptertitle}[1]{\chaptitlefont\MakeUppercase{#1}}
```

Here is a complete MWE:

[image]

```
\documentclass{memoir}% http://ctan.org/pkg/memoir
\renewcommand{\printchaptertitle}[1]{\chaptitlefont\MakeUppercase{#1}}
\begin{document}

\chapter{Sample Title}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks. Obviously, I am going to have to move my making of a compleat, documented memoir template up the priority stack.